# Make a script more generic for form validation

Tags: javascript

I've a large amount of this type of script:

```
// xx is the module name and will be different
$('[data-target="xx"]').validate({
    ignore: '',
    rules: {
        ORI_Text: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        saveFormDatas(form);
        return false;
    }
});
```

How can I make the `submitHandler` part generic for all my validate script as it's the same ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a function as the code you have is not reliant on any external state, only acting on the given arguments.

```
// this is now abstracted and you can pass it as the callback to many validations.
function onSubmit(form) {
  var $input = $(this) // if you need a reference to the validated element
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  saveFormDatas(form);
  return false;
}
$('[data-target="xx"]').validate({
    ignore: '',
    rules: {
        ORI_Text: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: onSubmit // the function is passed by reference
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. Two question for you. Why `onSubmit` is not `onSubmit()`? Second one is for `var input = $(this)`, what I get with that? Thanks.

Comment: You are passing a reference to the function as the callback. Javascript passes all objects and arrays by reference to save on memory, so you are able to re-use your `onSubmit` function. If you were to have the parenthesis you would be calling it. `onSubmit()` not passing the function to the `validate` callback. `this` inside the `onSubmit` function will be set to the HTMLFormElement `'[data-target="xx"]'` that you are validating. in case you need to get information from the validated element, or want to find another element relative to it eg. for a notification or error message.

Comment: It is wrapped as a jQuery object for convenience `$(this)`. You could do something like `$input.css({ background: 'red' })`

Answer (score 0):

You could use prototyping (maybe):

```
var someproto={
ignore: "",
rules: {
    ORI_Text: {
        required: true
    }
},
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    saveFormDatas(form);
    return false;
}
}

function some(rules){
  return Object.assign(Object.create(someproto),rules);
}
```

Usable like this:

```
$('[data-target="xx"]').validate(some({ignore:"a"}));
```

Putting *some* into jquery makes it even more easy to use:

```
jQuery.fn.some=function(rules){
 this.validate(some(rules));
};
```

Usable like this:

```
$('[data-target="xx"]').some({ignore:"a"});
```

Comment: And how I can change the fields to validate?

Comment: The `rules` part should and need change for every repetition script. It only the `submitHandler` that's fix.

Comment: @qatari: yes. Have a look at the examples. You can take everything that changes out of the proto and put it into the $(..).some({ additionally:0});